# Requesting URL to gnome-shell integration plugin for Firefox

Tags: gnome, firefox, gnome-shell-extension

Please give me the link to download the gnome-shell integration plugin which will allow me to subsequently install gnome-shell extensions via the web browser.

I just want the link to the plugin,

I do not want to do `apt-get dist-upgrade` or reinstall gnome.

The link to the plugin itself, should be available for all users to install.

I can't find the link on google or in the plugin/addon section.

Comment: The plugin is available at the Firefox extensions site.

Comment: I don't believe you. Link please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here you go!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gnome-integration/)

It is on Firefox's add-on page but is hard to find with the browser's local search machine.

Comment: That's for Thunderbird.

Comment: How does this answer get upvoted or selected as the correct answer? It is indeed for Thunderbird, yet the OP asks for a Firefox plugin (which still eludes us)

Answer (score 4):

I believe the confusion is that the plugin does not seem to be shipped as a plugin on ff addons. Instead, you find it in the repo for your distro. See the file lists below. Unfortunately, it also appears that not all the distros put it in the same "kind" of place.

Ubuntu: http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/amd64/gnome-shell/filelist
Fedora: http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/updates/19/x86_64/gnome-shell-3.8.4-3.fc19.x86_64.html

The actual plugin (as an xpi) may be available some place, but I can't find it.

Also, the link in @user118369 is to the tbird plugin which is something else entirely.

Answer (score 3):

This file is a PLUGIN of firefox (NOT an extension) and therefore it's stored under

```
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libgnome-shell-browser-plugin.so
```

you may check that in a fully functional (gnome!) firefox by entering this in the adressbar of firefox:

```
about:plugins
```

then scroll down to "Gnome Shell Integration", where you'll find it's path.

If the file is missing under /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins i have no idea  how to get it, it is probably part of gnome-shell itself (maybe reinstall?). Hope this helps

EDIT: Just fixed it! Boot a live image of gnome, mount your local hard-disk and drag that libgnome-shell-browser-plugin.so file to YourDisk/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins. I just fixed my FF/Gnome  :)